# Unprotected MongoDB server?

Tags: mongodb, security, database

I apologize beforehand if this is a stupid or a silly question in any way. Let's just say that I stumbled upon an unprotected MongoDB server belonging to a big company. I tried using a client to connect to the server, without entering a username and password and it connected successfully. Now, I'm not sure if I have access to the data inside the databases, but I can see that there are a few databases on it, and I believe that it's possible for me to create and drop databases on it (haven't tried). How big of a security flaw does this constitute? Please note that I haven't tampered or messed around with anything, I'm just asking so I can discern if this is indeed a security flaw that I should report, or a false positive. Shouldn't such access be limited to database administrators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see where this is going, there may be several cases.

1. It might be a developmental server and data is fake.
2. It may be abandoned
3. They must be running some maintenance during which some lazy devs, open the ports and security.

Most production databases are sealed enough, since you call it a "BIG" company, most probably they must have done it.
What ever might be the case depending on the company you can even be slapped with criminal notices, not every companies take bug review by 3rd parties in proper way. If they have a proper bug bounty program though they may offer you a reward. Tread with caution.

Comment: They do have a bug bounty program, and I will report it! Thank you sir

Comment: @IbraheemNofal Please accept the answer if you think it solved your problem